# How to force-install Xcode 4.3?

Tags: xcode4.3

I've read through a number of existing StackOverflow questions about Xcode 4 installation woes, but none of them quite match my configuration.

I started off with a MacBook Air with apps sucked over from an older MacBook Pro. During the migration process, it would seem that Xcode.app was pulled over, but /usr/include and friends were left behind.

So, I tried to install Xcode from the app store earlier, and got no feedback except for minutes of 'INSTALLING', with no status and no noticeable network load. I shut down (was running out of battery) and tried again later -- same behavior.

Then, I ran `sudo /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=all` to clean things up, rebooted, and tried again. Now, when I click the 'install' button in the app store, I'm prompted for my credentials, I see a little spinner for a second in the top-left of the window, and the UI reverts to its original state ("Install" as an option, etc.). Subsequent clicks on "Install" trigger the spinner for a second, but have no other noticeable side effects.

Are there any other rituals I should perform to clean my computer of whatever invalid state it's in so that I can get Xcode re-installed so that I can get /usr/include etc. back so that I can start compiling again?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might try installing the Xcode 4.3 dmg available from https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action. At least Installer.app has a log window that might show some useful errors if it fails.

Or if you want to keep trying the App Store version, open Console.app and watch the "All Messages" log while trying the install.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that the console was unenlightening. Trying the dev download now... thanks! I didn't know that they still had it online outside of the app store.

Comment: After a ridiculously slow download from Apple's servers, I got Xcode 4.2 installed, which is solving my immediate needs. However, Xcode itself is crashing consistently when I run it (UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION (NSInternalInconsistencyException): Couldn't load plug-in 'com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEiPhoneSupport' while firing fault for extension 'Xcode.Device.iPhonePlaceholder'). Something is definitely not well with my configuration. I'm going to try upgrading to 4.3 later today and see if that resolves things.

Comment: it is amazing how badly it sucks the installation process for apps on the app store, I came to this question because I am under the same situation in which I see "Installing" for minutes without any progress bar, deplorable for a company like Apple.